# pb with routing symfony2, some route generate 404

Tags: rest, symfony

i have two routes, it works with one and it does not work with each other, really it's very strange :'(

route don't work and api generate service not found when i do /user

```
ard_api_user_get:
pattern:  /user/{id}.{_format}
defaults: { _controller: BLAApiBundle:User:user, id: 0, _format: ~ }
requirements:
 _method: POST
 id:  \d+
```

route work when i do /userr

```
ard_api_user_getr:
pattern:  /userr/{id}.{_format}
defaults: { _controller: BLAApiBundle:User:user, id: 0, _format: ~ }
requirements:
    _method: POST
    id:  \d+
```

any help please

Comment: Did you try to clear your cache? Are you sure that you included your `routing.yml` into main config?

Comment: yes i'm cleared my cache, and my routing.yml is into my main config and when i do php app/console router:debug i found the route, but in my log I feel it adds me a slash at the end of my pattern and I do not know if this is normal or not

Comment: Symfony automatically trim trailing slash.

Comment: have you checked the routing.yml file indentation ?

Comment: yes I did, when I change the name of pattern /user to /blabla it work, is really strange :'(

Comment: I have about 50 road in the project, it gives me this problem with two routes: /venue and /user

Comment: They both go to the same controller action. Is that desired?

Comment: I added the second just to explain

Comment: I have this problem with the apache server, but it does not with nginx server

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add a htaccess in the racine of the symfony project,
these is the content of the file :

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```